# Filling attribute column with numbers 1-50 on repeat in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a large file of several hundred thousand polygons. It's too many to have an individual colour, so I want to create a column of numbers to which I can assign a random colour. So how do I create a column in the attribute of numbers 1 to 50 on repeat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a number going from 1 to 50 and repeat, you can use [the modulo `%` operator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?#id46) combined with the `@id` variable (older versions of QGIS can use `$id` instead) :

```
@id % 50 + 1
```

(the color can be directly randomized with QGIS expressions but that is not the OP question)